# laravel broadcast notifications without nodejs

Tags: laravel, notifications, runtime, chat

I am creating a website which requires notifications and live chats.The server where i will upload that website doesn't have nodejs installed on it and neither they will.I can not use pusher because it is paid service.Is there any way to broadcast notifications at runtime without using nodejs and pusher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel community is so powerful that you can use real-time chat without nodejs. There is a package called laravel-websockets:
https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/
behind the scene, it uses ratchet server
I don't know it will work with your server but surely you should give it a try.
If you have query you can comment it. I will surely reply to it
You can say it is a replacement for pusher and in the client-side you can use laravel echo library
https://github.com/laravel/echo